# How can i debug or handle the replication Session data causing the lazy unlocked in weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, jrockit

I am using weblogic server and facing with stuck thread,this thread dump contains wait on lock
Facing this issue: While my scheduler are start running, the call  going to respective folder(inbound location)  and call my file at some place it is not coming back and displaying this issue.

Here adding facing issue as requested:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=22 idx=0x54 tid=9647 prio=1 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon

                -- Blocked trying to get lock: weblogic/servlet/internal/session/ReplicatedSessionData@0x10ba4a060[lazy unlocked]

                at jrockit/vm/Threads.sleep(I)V(Native Method)

                at jrockit/vm/Locks.waitForThinRelease(Locks.java:955)[optimized]

                at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1083)[optimized]

                at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)[optimized]

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/session/ReplicatedSessionContext.lookupSession(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:437)[optimized]

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/session/ReplicatedSessionContext.getSessionInternal(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:257)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/session/ReplicatedSessionContext.getSessionInternal(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:249)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.getValidSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:3112)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.getSessionInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:2635)[optimized]

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.getSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2601)[inlined]

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl.getSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:1352)[optimized]

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2097)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2075)

                at weblogic/servlet/internal/ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)[optimized]

                at weblogic/servlet/provider/ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)

                at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)[optimized]

                at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

                at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please add WebLogic Server and JVM versions.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin  The version we are  using WebLogic Server:12.2x and JVM:1.8

Comment: Take a thread dump when the issue occurs and post it.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin please check the update facing issue

Comment: You are using JRockit but you say you are using java 8 ???

Comment: @Emmanuel Collin Sorry I posted wrongly. In development environment we will use the java8 and production environment it is jrockit

Comment: So, which version of WebLogic are you running in prod env ?